# C# Как вывести предложение в котором встречается нужное словосочетание

Tags: c#, поиск

Пишу бота для обработки текста(но это неважно), решил добавить поиск в тексте но столкнулся с проблемой.
Суть
я получаю файл из директории, из него текст.
пропускаю текст через split('.') получаю предложения пробегаю по массиву и сравниваю предложения через Contains - не работает

Использовал регулярные выражения выделив искомое в \bчто-то\b -тоже не сработало

дополнительной проблемой может быть грамотность людей.

reg- искомое словосочетание 
FileDire - директория файлов 
predlogenia - массив предложений

```
public static void SearchProces(string reg,string[] FileDire)
    {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < FileDire.Length; i1++)//по папкам документов
        {
            string[] file = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(FileDire[i1]);//файлы

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < file.Length; i2++)//по файлам
            {
                string strok = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file[i2]);
                string[] predlogenia = strok.Split('.');

                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < predlogenia.Length; i3++)//по предложениям
                {

                    bool result = Regex.IsMatch(predlogenia[i3].Replace("\n"," "), reg);

                    bool resulConstat = (predlogenia[i3].Replace("\n", " ")).Contains(reg.Replace("\b", ""));

                    string[] words = predlogenia[i3].Split(' ');


                    if (result || resulConstat)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(predlogenia[i3]);
                    }
                    //string[] words = predlogenia[i3].Split(' ');

                    //for (int i4=0;i4<words.Length;i4++)//по словам в предложении
                    //{

                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

reg =  судна Канатная

**исходный текст**

> Механизм, предназначенный для создания тягового
>   усилия на канате. В более широком смысле воротом называют рычаг,
>   совершающий при работе полный оборот У стройства, использующие принцип
>   ворота: Отвёртка (разница диаме- тров жала и ручки); Велосипед
>   (педали, вращающие звёздочку); Рулевое колесо автомобиля, штурвал
>   судна  Канатная лебедка для подъема опускания груза в шах- ты. Европа
>   ХIХ век В конструкции лебедки есть интересные инженерные решения: •
>   подвижный блок; • различие в диаметре вала; • противоположное
>   расположение воротов Эксперимент Задача Соберите ворот колодца с
>   ручкой. Привяжите канат и проведите эксперименты по подъему груза
>   Задача Постройте ворот, который используется в отвертке. Применяйте
>   цилиндры с разными диаметрами. Привяжите канат и проведите
>   эксперименты Задача Соберите ворот, используемый в велосипеде .
>   Применяйте колеса с разными диаметрами. Натяните резинку между
>   колесами. Проведите эксперимент по наблюдению изменения скорости малой
>   оси Задача Постройте ворот, который применяется в системе рулевого
>   колеса на судне Инструкция сборки колодца с ручкой Инструкция сборки
>   ворота с цилиндрами Инструкция сборки ворота велосипеда Инструкция
>   сборки системы рулевого колеса Ворот Ворот Применение в робототехнике
>   Пример Роботу необходимо поднять груз, используя конструкцию крана На
>   стреле расположен блок, через которую прокинута веревка. Робот
>   наматывает веревку на Ось Необходимо повысить усилие за счет
>   использования ворота Ворот Ворот

Он пропускается через split('.') и сравнивает каждое предложение
отдельно

**Правильное предложение**

> В более широком смысле воротом называют рычаг,
>   совершающий при работе полный оборот У стройства, использующие принцип
>   ворота: Отвёртка (разница диаме- тров жала и ручки); Велосипед
>   (педали, вращающие звёздочку); Рулевое колесо автомобиля, штурвал
>   судна  Канатная лебедка для подъема опускания груза в шах- ты

Comment: Можете привести пример входных данных (`reg` и `predlogenia`) для которых приведенный код не работает?

Comment: Поправил, теперь должно быть попонятнее

Comment: у меня ваш код отлично работает. Файлы, которые читаете, в какой кодировке? UTF-8?

Comment: Что-то у меня код работает нормально: https://ideone.com/On2V0M Проверьте, нет ли в `reg` или `predlogenia` некорректных символов

Comment: да кодировка  UTF-8, не могли бы вы залить весь ваш код в на pastebin.com/  и дать мне ссылку возможно я допускаю где-то глупую ошибку

Comment: код у меня совпадает точно с вашим, ничего нового вы там не найдете. Переменная strok у вас в режиме отладки содержит то, что вы ожидаете? Точно не имеете никаких проблем с кодировкой